# How to introduce myself to a new contact from a provider?

Tags: email

I would like to send a welcome/introduction letter to the person that will be my contact in a provider's company. I've looked around an couldn't find a proper one.
I'd like to write something such as the "Welcome aboard" types [some examples](https://www.thebalance.com/new-employee-welcome-aboard-letter-example-2064229) (not very formal but polite), but that seems to fit more for people coming to work in our company

Comment: From your description, maybe something like "Looking forward to working with you" would be more suiting than "Welcome Aboard"?

Comment: Maybe he works on a ship?

Comment: After looking for some examples I've found that the welcome aboard was quite typical in non formal context. No that I have a ship btw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for more of an *introduction* letter than a welcome letter. It doesn't have to be anything complicated; just introduce who you are and what your interaction will be in the future. Make sure to include your standard email signature with any contact info you want them to have.

> Hi Jane,
>
> My name is Aseques, and I'm the lead developer of the Winkling Widget. I just wanted to introduce myself since we'll be working together on Project XYZ. Please don't hesitate to contact me if you have any questions about the project. I look forward to working with you in the future!
>
> Regards,
>  Aseques
>  Developer at WebCorp
> 555-555-5555

Comment: I like your suggestion, it's just what I needed, thanks a lot

Comment: forgot to accept answer